# How do I check file modified in python as a boolean, so I can implement in IF Statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, path, listdir

Im trying to create a function where if file modified, then perform task. I am able to do this if a file exists by doing -

```
import os
file_path = 'C:/Hi/'
if os.listdir(file_path):
  do xyz
```

But how can i do xyz based on if a files date was modified?

```
os.path.getmtime(file_path)
```

Only gets the time but cant be used in my if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import os 
import time
no_of_seconds_since_last_check = 30
if time.time() - os.path.getmtime(file_path) < no_of_seconds_since_last_check : 
    print("doing xyz")
```

The `if` condition detects a file modification within the specified time span, preferably since the last check for modifications.

Comment: Thank you @claudio this worked. so to confirm what your code does is sets a number of seconds and if the file date modified is greater than that, then it prints xyz? can this be set to a speicific time in the day? like if file was not modified by 4pm then print xyz

Comment: since os.path.getmtime returns epoch time, what should I mention in no_of_seconds_since_last_check in order to check last 24 hours data

Comment: last 24 hours = 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds = 86400

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Maybe This You want**:

```
import os
from time import sleep
folder_path = r'C:/Hi/'

def check_if_modifed(files : list , data):

    while True:
        sleep(2)
        for file in files:

            last_modifed = os.path.getatime(file)
            if last_modifed != data[file]:


                print(f'{file} Modfied !')

                data[file] = last_modifed
                
if os.listdir(folder_path):
  

    files = os.listdir(folder_path)

    current_data = {}
    for file in files:


        current_data [file] = os.path.getatime(file)

    try:

        check_if_modifed(files , current_data)
    except:

        print('Program Finish!')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).